# How do you select multiple row values as column values in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables linked by ID (simplified example below):

```
Table 1

ID     NAME
1      John
2      Frank

Table 2

ID     DAY     TIME_FROM    TIME_TO
1      Sun     8:00         15:00
1      Mon     8:00         15:00
1      Tue     NULL         NULL
1      Wed     NULL         NULL
1      Thu     NULL         NULL
1      Fri     8:00         15:00
1      Sat     8:00         15:00
2      Sun     8:00         15:00
...
```

What I would like is a query to return ideally the abbreviated days for each ID in one field like this:

```
ID     NAME    DAYS 
1      John    S M F S 
2      Frank   S M T W T F S
```

or perhaps:

```
ID     NAME    SUN    MON   TUE    
1      John    TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
2      Frank   TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
```

Prefer the first solution if its possible.

Comment: The second one is a simple `PIVOT`, search for this keyword with your favourite internet search service. The first one could be achieved with `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: With the first option, if you go with the single letter solution, there will be circumstances where you will be unable to tell whether saturday or sunday, or tuesday or thursday are returned.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes I would probably increase the character count to 3 - just had the initials for simplicity of the example

Comment: If you can use 3 characters as @Strawberry says, it will avoid the confusion. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. **For first solution:**

   ```
   SELECT T1.ID,T1.Name,
           GROUP_CONCAT(T2.`DAY` SEPARATOR ' ') as Day
   FROM Table1 T1 JOIN
        Table2 T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id
   GROUP BY T1.ID,T1.Name
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   ID  NAME    DAY
   1   John    Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed
   2   Frank   Sun
   ```

   **NB:** Using 3 letters to avoid the confusion between `Sat` and `Sun`.
   See the result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/767fdc/28).
2. **For second solution:**

   ```
   SELECT T1.ID,T1.Name,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (COALESCE(TIME_FROM,TIME_TO) IS NOT NULL  AND `DAY` ='Sun') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as SUN,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (COALESCE(TIME_FROM,TIME_TO) IS NOT NULL  AND `DAY` ='Mon') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as MON,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (COALESCE(TIME_FROM,TIME_TO) IS NOT NULL  AND `DAY` ='Tue') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as TUE,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (COALESCE(TIME_FROM,TIME_TO) IS NOT NULL  AND `DAY` ='Wed') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as WED,
           MAX(CASE WHEN (COALESCE(TIME_FROM,TIME_TO) IS NOT NULL  AND `DAY` ='Thu') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as THU,
       MAX(CASE WHEN (COALESCE(TIME_FROM,TIME_TO) IS NOT NULL  AND `DAY` ='Fri') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as FRI,
       MAX(CASE WHEN (COALESCE(TIME_FROM,TIME_TO) IS NOT NULL  AND `DAY` ='Sat') THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as SAT
   FROM Table1 T1 JOIN
        Table2 T2 ON T1.Id=T2.Id
   GROUP BY T1.ID,T1.Name
   ```

   **Explanation:**

   `COALESCE` will be useful to check both `TIME_FROM` and `TIME_TO` are `NULL`.

   **Result** (with the given example):

   ```
   ID  NAME    SUN     MON     TUE     WED     THU     FRI     SAT
   1   John    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
   2   Frank   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
   ```

   Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/767fdc/23).

Comment: Bringing to perfection?)

Comment: @Notulysses: What you mean? Am I missing something?

Comment: @RagingBull How would you exclude days with NULL times in the First example?

Comment: @RagingBull ignore previous comment re: excluding null days.  Simple good 'ol WHERE! **facepalm** Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function

```
SELECT t1.ID,t1.NAME,
       GROUP_CONCAT(`DAY` SEPERATOR ' ') as `DAYS`
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.ID=t2.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID,t1.NAME
```

Comment: How would you check for and remove days with null time values?